# Axios await call interfered in other function call

Tags: https, axios, nestjs

when i uncomment the axios call the **ret** variable returns {}, but when i comment the axios call **it** returns a filled object with the certificate information. I just don't know why the **axios** call interfere in **https get**

```js
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as https from 'https';
import { DetailedPeerCertificate, TLSSocket } from 'tls';
@Injectable()
export class CertificateValidationService {

    constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) { }

    certificateInfoCallBAck(domain: string):Promise<DetailedPeerCertificate> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            const options = {
                hostname: domain,
                port: 443,
                path: '/',
                method: 'GET'
            }
            
            const req = https.get(options, (res) => {            
                req.end()
                resolve(((res.socket) as TLSSocket).getPeerCertificate(true));
            });
        });
    }

    async getValidationDateFromCertificate(domain: string) {
        try {
            //const test = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get(`https://${domain}`);
            let ret = await this.certificateInfoCallBAck(domain); 
            console.log(ret);

            const validFrom = (typeof ret === 'object' && 'valid_from' in ret) ? ret['valid_from']:'';
            const validTo = (typeof ret === 'object' && 'valid_to' in ret) ? ret['valid_to']:'';
            return {validFrom,validTo,certificate:true}
        } catch (error) {
            return {info: "domain without certificate", certificate:false}
        }
    }
}
```

[the return with axios call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCFiU.png)

[the return without axios call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDAl9.png)

Comment: I think it could be related to the fact that Axios is also using `https` under the hood. https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/http.js#L9

Comment: please post the image as text.